# What is the best way to create a large set of dummy data?

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsarray

I'm trying to create a set of dummy data to put into a program, and I was wondering what the best way to do that was.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what kind of data you need: random numbers? strings? bytes?

Comment: Put something meaningful inside mysql, then get it back.

Comment: I have a radial graph that I need to add random points to, so I need random numbers

Answer (score 1):

See arc4random(). It's the standard function for generating random numbers.